# Check if string is number in android

Tags: android, string, numbers

I have three text fields all which are numbers or a decimal number.

They are accepted as strings which are later converted.

However, i want to validate these fields so that only the numbers or decimal numbers are accepted.

Whats the easiest way to ensure that these fields are only characters 0-9.

I would prefer an if statement but any solution would be nice!

Comment: use this regex `^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$` .

Comment: do i place it in the if statement?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `string.matches` method which accepts a regex as an argument.

```
if(string.matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"))
{
System.out.println("Matches");
}
else
{
System.out.println("No Match");
}
```

Comment: How would i say does not match this string

Comment: Whats the opposite of this regex so it only accepts letters and not numbers or decimal.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I played some scenarios without the non-capturing part "?:" and didn't find any difference. Could you shed some light on why we need it? thx!

Comment: Hi @Donald. Most probably we should avoid capturing groups unless we want the characters inside that group. Here a non-capturing group would be enough because of condition checking.. And also note that if we want to make more than one patterns as optional, we should need a group (cap or non-cap group).

Comment: This doesn't capture negative numbers

Answer (score 18):

If you are looking for a way to just check if the string contains digits (so check for integer values), use the native 
[`TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(CharSequence str)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isDigitsOnly(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Answer (score 2):

If you are inflating those textviews from xml you can just use:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the string to integer and if the string contains any characters it will show an error so that way you can know if it contains any digit

```
 String s = numen.getText().toString();
    try {
        int d = Integer.parseInt("d");

        Toast.makeText(this, d, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong input please input valid detail ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this util method which uses the same regex as used in `TextView`.

```
fun isPhoneNumber(number: String): Boolean {
    return if (number.isEmpty()) {
        false
    } else {
        Patterns.PHONE.matcher(number).matches()
    }
}
```

just note from the `Patterns.PHONE` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns#PHONE)

> This pattern is intended for searching for things that look like they
> might be phone numbers in arbitrary text, not for validating whether
> something is in fact a phone number.  It will miss many things that
> are legitimate phone numbers.
>
> The pattern matches the following:
>
> Optionally, a + sign followed immediately by one or more digits. Spaces, dots, or dashes
> may follow.
> Optionally, sets of digits in parentheses, separated by spaces, dots, or dashes.
> A string starting and ending with a digit, containing digits, spaces, dots, and/or dashes.

Answer (score 0):

```java
String trim = "Dv202";
Boolean CONTDigit = false;
char[] chars = trim.toCharArray();
for (char c : chars) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        CONTDigit = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer only contains code. I recommend that you don't only post code as an answer, but _also_ provide an explanation about what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes. Can you [edit] your answer to include this?