# Getting number format exception in android

Tags: java, android, database

I am newbie to android and have implemented a class in which data is coming from database, I have used cursor but it gives me `NumberformatException`.

My code is:

```
package com.example.login;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b,b1;
EditText e1,e2,e3;
SQLiteDatabase a;
database db;
Cursor r;
String s="";
String d="";
String w,t;
int q;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        q=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText()+"");
        w=e2.getText()+"";
        t=e3.getText()+"";

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                a=db.getWritableDatabase();
                a.execSQL("insert into data values("+q+",'"+w+"','"+t+"');");
                db.close();
            }
        });
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                a=db.getReadableDatabase();
                r=a.rawQuery("select name from data", null);
                System.out.println("========cursor======"+r.toString());
                if(r.getCount()>0){
                    r.moveToNext();
                    s+=r.getString(0);
                }
                s+=r.getString(0);
                db.close();
                /*a=db.getReadableDatabase();
                r=a.rawQuery("select pass from data", null);
                d+=r.getString(0);
                db.close();*/
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public database(Context context) {
        super(context, "data", null, 2);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        arg0.execSQL("create table data(cd int,name string ,pass string);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        arg0.execSQL("drop table data;");
        onCreate(arg0);

    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379): Process: com.example.login, PID: 28379
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.login/com.example.login.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at com.example.login.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
07-28 17:06:47.988: E/AndroidRuntime(28379):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: On what line does it give the Number Format Exception? Please dump the exception here or highlight the lines.

Comment: r.moveToFirst(); insted of  r.moveToNext();

Comment: @Janno -at this line, r.moveToNext();

Comment: @ sulphuric did you check

Comment: @Janno - Will it work?let me try.Thank you brother

Comment: @ sulphuric  let me knw what you r getting

Comment: No change,Still the error is same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118531/discussion-between-v-v-and-sulphuric-acid).

Comment: This code makes no sense to me. You create a view with `e1` and then you expect, that is already has a value in it? Have you defined a default value? If not, then remove `q=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText()+"");` from `onCreate`.

Comment: A lot of issues in this code. Starting from variable names over using "global" variables ... You need to insert the data that is actual at the time the button is clicked, not at Activity creation time.

Answer (score 0):

the error should be related to this:

```
q=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText()+"");
```

I expect that `e1.getText()` is empty string.
Remove it and initialise `q` with a number.

Comment: Initialising `q` won't change anything, since `e1.getText` would still be empty.

Comment: sorry I'd say "remove it and initialise with a number". Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

This means that you must ensure the values to be parsed. `""` (nothing) is not a number. Set the text to some initial value such as: `e1.setText("42");` to ensure correct parsing, or dont parse, if the String is null/empty.

*note that onCreate gives no chance for the user to alter its data. You are basically always getting an empty value*.

```
if(e1.getText()!=null && !e1.getText().isEmpty()){
   q=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText()+"");
} else {
   Log.v(YourTag,"no number to parse, setting -1 instead");
   q = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`e1.getText()` returns empty so `Integer.parseInt(e1.getText()+"")` tries to parse empty string to int. First, you can check `e1.getText().toString()` [is numeric.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262475/check-if-string-is-number-in-android)

```
private boolean checkStringIsNumeric(String string) {
    return string.matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");
}

if (checkStringIsNumeric(e1.getText().toString()))
    q=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
```